# Need module in pulseaudio 11.1 build

Tags: pulseaudio

When this is released for Zesty, how can I make sure module *mudule-combine-sink* is included? The current Zesty version doesn't have it.

Answer (score 0):

Zesty reached the end of line support for months.
But I have full PulseAudio 11.1 on Zesty, work quite well.
Add Bionic repo to apt sources.list, update and install PulseAudio 11.
[PulseAudio 11.1 Zesty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Yhms.jpg)
Remove Bionic source from apt source.list
Then, you're good to go